# Something to create labels and regions in entity framework designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4.1, edmx-designer

i have this question about Visual Studio 2010 entity framework designer. Is there a tool that can allow the user to create regions or notes or something like that in the entity designer? I ask this because i have a very large model and it will be useful to have something like coloured regions or regions with notes so that the user can have a better reading of the model.

Regards,
Gonzalo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. VS 11 has better designer which allows you separating different parts of model to separate diagram and changing colors of entities but adding labels is probably still not possible.

Comment: Yes, i installed VS11 beta yesterday and i saw the new improvements. There are pretty nice compared to the vs2010 entity designer.